# Which way of storing this data in MongoDB is more performant? Caching max/min values in Item collection or on-the-fly calculation based on all bids?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with a startup building an exchange platform where commodities from an Item collection with around 50,000 documents can be bought and sold by users, who create buy and sell bids for these items.

For our "buy it now"/"sell it now" features, it's required to calculate the best buy and sell bids for an item. Currently we are calculating these on the fly with an index in the UserBids collection on the buy and sell bids field (for a given Item document, let's say with ID 1234, we'll find all UserBids for item 1234 and get the maximum buy bid and minimum sell bid). This is used to present every user with the best price they can buy/sell an item instantly at, and requires a lot of queries on the UserBids collection, but prevents having to update a canonical 'best' price for each item.

I'm wondering if it would be more performant for the Item schema to have a MaxBuy and MinSell field. This would require the MaxBuy and MinSell fields for an Item document to receive an update every time a user enters a new bid, using something like `Items.update({id: itemId, $or: [{maxBuy: {$lt: currentBuyBid}}, {maxBuy: null}]})`. We would still have to perform the same number of queries to show a user the best price, but the queries wouldn't require an aggregation, and as the exchange grows, we expect the UserBids collection to grow much more than the Items collection (which should remain relatively the same size)

Bids may be added/modified regularly, but we expect the volume of users checking best buy/sell prices to be about 10-100 times greater. Is there a good way to evaluate which one of these approaches would be best?

Comment: Ultimately what you are asking breaks down to this. "Is it faster to record the distance between two points in a reference I can look up by index, or is it faster to walk around the world and measure the distance between the points as I go?". If the answer is not self apparent then you probably shouldn't even be asking the question. Should we really code up solutions as the basis of IP for your start up?

Comment: Thanks @Neil-lunn, I appreciate the comment, though perhaps not the attitude. If it makes any difference, the reason I was second-guessing my own intuition on this is because I'm an entry-level developer, and the senior-level dev who set everything up the way it is told me my proposal was a 'premature optimization' when I suggested it. Also, if you'd like to add this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: You misunderstood; the senior dev set everything up to use what I believe you're referring to as the "walk around the world" method. Caching the max/min values was my proposal.

Comment: Then perhaps you are indeed learning from someone at least if it was not your senior dev. But maybe you should still ask them the poignant question. The purpose of a cache it to keep costly calculations in a quick and useful lookup. But a cache still comes at a cost. So does the predicted usage pattern outweigh the effective utility of a cache in your circumstances? I Cant tell. No-one can tell on the information provided. It seems the real answer relies on empirical data that has not been made available. And maybe your own people have. Hence, too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly depends on which use-case is more frequent and performance-critical:

1. a user placing a bid which would trigger a recalculation of said fields
2. someone checks the price

When you assume that the latter use-case is more frequent, this is the one you should optimize for.